# How to write the probability density function of a mixed random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, measure-theory

We consider a random variable X with density 
$$p_\theta=e^{\theta T(x)-A(\theta)}h(x)$$
with respect to a dominating measure $\mu$

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be i.i.d. from the distribution of X. Suppose that actually the value of $X$ is measured when X is larger than $c$. That is, we observe, $Z_1,...,Z_n$ where $Z_i=c(1-Y_i)+Y_i X_i$, $Y_i=\mathbb{1}_{X_i>c}$. Then what is the density of $Z_i$ and relative to which measure?

I'm trying to write the density function of $Z_i$ but I find $P(Z_i=c)=\int_{-\infty}^{c}p_\theta(x)dx$. So I cannot write it as a density function. And the hint is to write the density function with a new measure different from $\mu$ but I still cannot figure out.

Comment: Try $\mu+\delta_c$ as the dominating measure.

Comment: I got a density function like $p_\theta (z)1(z>c) + \delta_c(z)P(x<c)$ relative to $\mu+\delta_c$, but how does the integral of this density relative to the new measure equals the CDF of $Z_i$?

Comment: @Did, Can you be more specific? Since I'm beginner about measure theory.